# Помогите решить задачку

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая определяет, сколько в матрице есть K -значных чисел,
сумма цифр каждого из которых кратна R.

В первой строке записаны через пробел размеры матрицы: количество строк N и количество столбцов M ( 1 ≤ N , M ≤ 100 ). В следующих N строках записаны строки матрицы, в каждой – по M натуральных чисел, разделённых пробелами. Затем в двух разных строках вводятся числа K и R .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
N,M = map(int, input().split())
a = []
c = 0
for i in range(N):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

K = int(input())
R = int(input())
summ = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        if a[i][j] >= 10**(K-1) and a[i][j] < 10**K:
            while a[i][j] > 0:
                summ +=a [i][j] % 10
                a[i][j] //= 10
            if summ % R == 0:
                c += 1
            summ = 0

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# проверка количества цифр в числе
def is_n_digits(number, figures):
    return 0 < number // (10 ** (figures - 1)) < 10


# проверка на кратность
def is_multiplicity(number, rate):
    total = 0
    while number > 0:
        total += number % 10
        number //= 10
    return total % rate == 0


n, m = map(int, input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
k = int(input())
r = int(input())

count = 0
for row in range(n):
    for col in range(m):
        if all([is_n_digits(matrix[row][col], k), is_multiplicity(matrix[row][col], r)]):
            count += 1

print(count)
```